# Bootstrap 3 Registration Form PHP

Tags: php, html, forms, twitter-bootstrap, registration

this is my register.php page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="it">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>Circolari 2.0</title>
<link rel=stylesheet type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.css">
<link rel=stylesheet type="text/css" href="css/styles.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
           <div class="form-signup">
                <b><h1 class="text-center">Registrazione</h1></b>
                <br>
                <form action="register.php" method="post">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="left-inner-addon">
                            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i>
                            <input class="form-control focus" type="text" placeholder="Nome" name="nome">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="left-inner-addon">
                            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i>
                            <input class="form-control focus" type="text" placeholder="Cognome" name="cognome">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="left-inner-addon">
                            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></i>
                            <input class="form-control focus" type="text" placeholder="Email" name="email">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="left-inner-addon">
                            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock"></i>
                            <input class="form-control focus" type="password" placeholder="Password" name="password">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <button class="btn btn-info" type="submit" name="submit_button">Registrati</button>
                    <a class="btn btn-warning" href="index.php">Home</a>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
</body>
</html>

<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit_button']))
{
    // Definisco le variabili Nome, Cognome, Email e Password
    $nome=$_POST['nome'];
    $cognome=$_POST['cognome'];
    $email=$_POST['email'];
    $password=$_POST['password'];

    if ($nome=="" or $cognome="" or $email="" or $password="")
    {
        echo "Tutti i campi sono obbligatori";
    }
    else
    {
        // Includo il file di configurazione
        include('config.php');

        // Connessione al database
        $conn=mysqli_connect("$db_host", "$db_username", "$db_password", "$db_name") or die (mysqli_error($conn)); 

        // Controllo se Email è già registrata
        $stmt=$conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE Email=?");
        $stmt->bind_param("s", $email);
        $stmt->execute();
        $result=$stmt->get_result();

        // Conto i risultati
        $count=$result->fetch_assoc();

        // Se Email e Password combaciano, otterrò un solo risultato
        if($count==1)
        {
            echo "Utente già registrato!";
        }
        else
        {
            // Query Database
            $stmt=$conn->prepare("INSERT INTO $tbl_name (Nome, Cognome, Email, Password) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)");
            $stmt->bind_param("ssss", $nome, $cognome, $email, $password);
            $stmt->execute();
            $result=$stmt->get_result();

            if ($stmt->execute())
            {
                echo "Registrazione effettuata con successo!";
                echo ($nome);
                echo ($cognome);
                echo ($email);
                echo ($password);
            }
            else 
            {
                echo (mysqli_error($conn));
            }
        }
    }
}
?>
```

The problem is that when I click the SUBMIT button, in the database i have all blank columns except 'Nome'. I really can't understand the problem.
P.S.: I added echo of all variables and in fact only $nome is printed at the screen. Thank you all!

Comment: echo $sql and see what it contains.

Comment: You really need to use prepared statements, you are **wide open** to SQL injection attacks on your script.

Comment: This is what i see when I echo variables and sql query: Registrazione effettuata con successo!CristianoINSERT INTO utenti (Nome, Cognome, Email, Password) VALUES ('Cristiano', '', '', ''). Another strange thing is that if I register with the same email I can't register because scripts says that user already exists (I check email in the first part of PHP script) but If I go check in database onle variable $nome is displayed, the others are blank

Comment: I updated The code with statement to prevent MySQL Injection

Answer (score 0):

Im pretty sure you need top have a unique "id=xxx" for your input fields, otherwise it won't be sent in the form post